# Solution to AHK sending too many events when holding down a mouse button?

Tags: autohotkey

When using three different methods of holding down the left mouse button:

```
Mouseclick, left, 0, 0, 1, , D, R
```

or

```
Send {LButton down}
```

or

```
Click down
```

the game I'm making a macro for logs me out complaining that I'm sending too many actions. I tested this by itself as a script, like:

```
F3::
    Click down
    return
```

So there's no chance other code is causing it.

I was wondering if there are any settings I can use (by settings I mean like `CoordMode, Mouse, Screen`) or any other solution to perhaps prevent whatever rapid event sending AHK is using to simulate a mouse button being held down. Is there any possible fix I can try? I'm open to testing any ideas.

Comment: Try setting the Speed(the parameter you left blank in `MouseClick`) and also try different [SendMode](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SendMode.htm)

Comment: @Oleg Ok, tested `SendMode Input` and `SendMode Play` with 
`Mouseclick, left, 100, 100, 1, 50, D`
 
 `Send {LButton down}` 
 
 `SendEvent {LButton down}` 
 
 `SendEvent {Click 200, 200, down}` 
 
 `Click down` 

but got the same problem every time. It must be something to do with the game not liking how AHK fundamentally sends input from keys being held down.

Comment: Autohotkey doesn't work with some games, check the following thread for some more things you can try: https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=11084

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could introduce a `Sleep` like so:

```
LButton::
while (GetKeyState("LButton", "P"))
{
    MouseClick, left
    Sleep, 100
}
return
```

Though I personally dislike binding the mouse click to behaviours via the same mouse click, as it can lead to results that are difficult to get out of.

Here's an example with a toggleable hotkey.

```
Insert::
SendInput, {LButton Down}
loop
{
    Sleep, 100
    if getkeystate("Insert", "p") ; Hold for a second as the Sleep will delay recognition.
    {
        SendInput, {LButton Up}            
        break
    }
}
return
```

**Edited per the comments:**

```
Insert::
SendInput, {LButton Down}
KeyWait, Insert, D
SendInput, {LButton Up}
return
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without clicking? Because clicking is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Viziionary The second example begins clicking once you press Insert, and continues until it's pressed again. Any key or key combo can accomplish the same.

Comment: Yeah this solution sends click events, not hold the LMB down. The question is about holding down a mouse button, not clicking.

Comment: @Viziionary Gotcha. I misinterpreted the post based on the click example and "too many actions". I've edited the answer with an example for button down/up.